# Is there some pattern on Random() method?

Tags: android, design-patterns, random

I started making a project where there are goats! Yeah Goats.
Currently there is only one function, when I click a goat, it create another goat in a **Random** position.
I realized that there is a pattern of positions:

[image: I've made red lines on patterns]

Here is the code:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    private int[] arrGoats = new int[5];
    private RelativeLayout battlefield;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        battlefield = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_battlefield);

        arrGoats[0] = R.drawable.amarelo;
        arrGoats[1] = R.drawable.azul;
        arrGoats[2] = R.drawable.branco;
        arrGoats[3] = R.drawable.verde;
        arrGoats[4] = R.drawable.vermelho;

        criarCabra(60, 100);

    }

    private void criarCabra(float x, float y) {
        int cabraImg = arrGoats[new Random().nextInt(4)];

        ImageView cabra = new ImageView(this);
        cabra.setImageResource(cabraImg);
        cabra.setX(x);
        cabra.setY(y);

        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) new LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.width = 150;
        params.height = 120;
        cabra.setLayoutParams(params);

        cabra.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                criarCabra(new Random().nextInt(2000), new Random().nextInt(1000));
            }
        });

        battlefield.addView(cabra);
    }
}
```

I would like to know why this pattern is being created although I'm using `Random().NextInt()` to define goats positions.

Am I crazy?

Comment: what you mean by pattern ?

Comment: @blackbelt Look at the picture, the goats position is a diagonal pattern.

Comment: Try using a single instance of Random throughout the program instead of creating a new instance every time you need a number.

Comment: @blackbelt There is no good reason to create these extra objects that immediately become candidates for garbage collection.

Comment: There is a discussion about the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726991/mathrandom-aint-so-random

Comment: @blackbelt Creating multiple instances of `Random` in quick succession will give you bizarre results like this if seeding is done via a low resolution peek at the clock, which is common to many PRNG implementations.

Comment: @pjs The random is seeded with `System.currentTimeMillis() + System.identityHashCode(this)` where `this` is the `Random` object (leading to different seed for each `Random` here).

Comment: how fast are you clicking?

Comment: @laalto and I'm guessing that the actual seeds being produced are close to sequential.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282628/why-are-initial-random-numbers-similar-when-using-similar-seeds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you're creating a new `Random` object each time. In Android, the [initial seed is derived from current time and the identity hash code](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Random.java#65):

```
public Random() {
     // Note: Using identityHashCode() to be hermetic wrt subclasses.
     setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis() + System.identityHashCode(this));
}
```

For two objects created in sequence, the identity hash codes are close to each other. On my Android KitKat Dalvik VM, I get identity hash codes that differ only by 32.

The `currentTimeMillis()` does not provide much difference to the seeds either.

The random itself is a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) of the form

```
random[i+1] = a * random[i] + b (mod c)
```

where `random[0]` is the seed and `a`, `b` and `c` are parameters.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282628/why-are-initial-random-numbers-similar-when-using-similar-seeds), similar seeds indeed produce similar results in linear congruential generators:

> The reason you're seeing similar initial output from nextDouble given similar seeds is that, because the computation of the next integer only involves a multiplication and addition, the magnitude of the next integer is not much affected by differences in the lower bits.

Hence, your two successively generated `Random`s with default seeds will produce values that seem to be correlated and make your goats get positioned on a line.

To fix it, use the same `Random` object and/or a more random pseudorandom generator than a linear congruential one.

Comment: Thanks to @pjs for some of the research.

Answer (score 5):

You are creating new instances of `Random` with every call to `criarCabra` and every invocation of `onClick`.  Create a single static instance of `Random`, then re-use it.

Unless you really know what you're doing and have a very good reason to be doing it, the best practice is to only create one instance of `Random` per program and then poll it whenever you need additional values.

Comment: Waiting for response :D

Comment: ... and how would creating a new random object cause the behavior seen by OP?

Comment: @laalto Via an interaction with the seeding mechanism.  Java's `Random` is a linear congruential generator, those stinkers are infamous for producing collinear results when seeds are sequentially related. See the brief discussion of Marsaglia's theorem on the [LCG Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Advantages_and_disadvantages_of_LCGs).